# HTML action using ASP.net

Tags: css, asp.net

The link works fine but  CSS doesn't  behave the way it should. The HTML Only one works perfectly. I think the issue is to do with the span it stays behind the button.

Buttons should behave like here:

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/1832/Pure-CSS3-Animated-buttons

```
<li><div class="drag-item" draggable="true">
@Html.ActionLink("Sales", "Sales", "Home",  new { @class = "round" }, new { @class = "round yellow" })<span>Tender Sales - Customer Balances etc</span>
```

THIS ONE WORKS PERFECTLY

```
  <li><div class="drag-item" draggable="true"><a href="/finance" class="round red">Finance<span class="round">Tender Sales - Customer Balances etc</span></a></li>
```

Comment: If it works perfectly when hardcoded as HTML, then why not inspect the result of hitting your Razor view to see what HTML it generated - then compare?

Comment: What does your rendered HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

Hi guy's sorry for any time I wasted and thanks. I have found the solution. Posting here for those who may need it.

```
    <a href="@Url.Action("View", "Controller")" class="Css Classname">


     **<li><div class="drag-item" draggable="true"><a 
     href="@Url.Action("Welcome", "Helloworld")" class="round 
    yellow">Sales<span class="round" aria-hidden="true">Tender Sales - 
    Customer Balances etc</span></a></li>**
```